# Passing data between login controller and FirstviewController when using SWRevealViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController for a slide out menu on the FirstViewController of a tabbed application. I am instantiating the revealviewcontroller from the login controller.revealview controller connects to tabbarcontroller and tableview controller as shown below.

[Image showing viewcontrollers in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN4kO.png)

**Question**: I am trying to pass the username from the logincontroller to FirstViewController, but am not able to figure how . Any help appreciated

@IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any) {

```
    if emailField.text == "" || passwordField.text == "" {

        message.text = "Please appropriate login credentials."

    }

    else {

         FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {


                let DestinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "realview") as! SWRevealViewController

                DestinationVC.loadView()

                let  firstVC = DestinationVC.frontViewController as! FirstViewController


                self.present(DestinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

              if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

     firstVC.Displaylabel.text = currentUser.displayName


                }

                } else {

                self.message.text = "\(error)"
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Updated above code after more research. Still not able to pass the data to firstviewcontroller.getting an error. most of the examples on the website use prepareforsegue. am instantiating using storyboard ID. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your login view controller should be your initial view controller. After successful login, set revealviewcontroller class as rootview controller. And you can save user credentials as userdefault object. As far as I know I have followed this procedure.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let frontviewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(navigationcontrollerid) as? UINavigationController
            let rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(id) as? UITableViewController
            let mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()
            mainRevealController.frontViewController = frontviewcontroller
            mainRevealController.rearViewController = rearViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and also get the user defaults value in viewdidload,

```
if let userName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userName") {
                print("the name is ", (userName))

            }
```

check whether this works

Comment: Comment Part1/2: Thank You @thipoo24 for response. I have added the following code in my logincontroller               
 if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "realview") {
                        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }   if let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard {
                        defaults.set(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName, forKey: "userName")
                        }

Comment: Comment Part 2/2: And in the First view controller (storyboardimage attached in my question) am trying to access the name like this. if let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard{
            let name = defaults.string(forKey: "userName")
            Displaylabel.text = "name"
        }. I am still not able to access the username by doing this. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank You for the response. My storyboard doesn't have a Navigation controller. I have provided an answer that worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Following changes worked :

In the Log in view controller, saved user id to userdefaults

//aftersuccesfull login

if let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

```
         {

                let currentuser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

                let userID = currentuser?.uid


                defaults.set(userID, forKey: "userID")
                defaults.synchronize()
         }
```

In the First View controller

//After view did load

```
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let user = defaults.string(forKey: "userID")
        Displaylabel.text = user
```